# How to calculate $\int_{0}^1 \frac{(\cos x-1)^2}{x^2} $?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate  $\int_{0}^1 \frac{(\cos x-1)^2}{x^2} $ ?
I tried integration by parts but it only got worse.(I don't want to use Si$(x)$ function) Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Wolfram gives the result as $2 \text{Si}(1) - \text{Si}(2) - 4 \sin^4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx 0.0754312$.

Comment: The $Si(x)$ functions were created exactly to give an answer to a question like yours. So why would you not use them?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos See [https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351190/85343](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351190/85343)

Comment: @FelixMarin That solution uses to $\operatorname{Si}$ function, which the OP wishes to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Expand the numerator: $(1-\cos x)^2 = 1 -2\cos x + \cos^2x = 3/2 -2\cos x + \cos(2x)/2$, and notice that
$$
\int \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x = -a\mathrm{Si}(ax) - \frac{\cos(ax)}{x} + C,
$$
where $\mathrm{Si}(x)$ is the sine integral. You can solve it integrating by parts.

This method will give you as a result:
$$
\int \frac{(1-\cos x)^2}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x = 2\mathrm{Si}(x) - \mathrm{Si}(2x) - \frac{4\sin^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{x} + C.
$$

Therefore,
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{(1-\cos x)^2}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x = 2\mathrm{Si}(1) - \mathrm{Si}(2) - 4\sin^4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx 0.0754312.}
$$

If you do not want to use the sine integral function, integrate a series representation of the integrand, for example, but I do not understand why you do not want to use it if it was created explicitly for this cases.

Comment: This lovely technique can more generally prove$$\int_0^x\frac{\left(1-\cos(at)\right)^2}{t^2}dt=2a\operatorname{Si}(ax)-a\operatorname{Si}(2ax)-\frac{4\sin^4\frac{ax}{2}}{x}.$$

Comment: Of course! I answered the OP question, but you can generalize this problem.